# run cmake command via subprocess.Popen or subprocess.run

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake

I'm new to python and I'm trying to run my cmake via python program using subprocess.
this is my code:

```
test_path = "/home/yaodav/Desktop/test_clone_git/test/"
cmake_build_command = "cmake -Bcmake-debug-build -H. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=debug -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/gcc -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/c++ -Bcmake-debug-build -H. -DSYTEM_ARCH=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-7.4.0"
cmake_link_command = "cmake --build cmake-debug-build --target all"
cmake_command = [test_path, cmake_build_command, cmake_link_command]

try:
    out = subprocess.run(cmake_command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    stdout, stderr = out.communicate()
    print(stdout)
    print(stderr)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

but when I'm running it im getting

> 'Permission denied'

I checked my python file permission and

> -rwxrwxrwx. 1 yaodav yaodav 4387 Nov  3 05:05 git_puller.py

how do I fix it?

Comment: The first argument to the `subprocess.run()` (or `subprocess.Popen()`) is either a **list**, which **first element** is a **program** and others - the program's argument, or a single **string** containing a **command line** (a program and its arguments separated by a space). But you pass a **list** of **command lines**. This wouldn't work.

Comment: so how do I send few commands and not just one?